# SELECT DISTINCT on one column, return multiple other columns (SQL Server)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I'm trying to write a query that returns the most recent GPS positions from a GPSReport table for each unique device. There are 50 devices in the table, so I only want 50 rows returned.

Here is what I have so far (not working)

```
SELECT TOP(SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT device_serial) FROM GPSReport) * FROM GPSReport AS G1
RIGHT JOIN
(SELECT DISTINCT device_serial FROM GPSReport) AS G2
ON G2.device_serial = G1.device_serial
ORDER BY G2.device_serial, G1.datetime DESC
```

This returns 50 rows, but is not returning a unique row for each device_serial. It returns all of the reports for the first device, then all of the reports for the second device, etc.

Is what I'm trying to do possible in one query?

Comment: Giving the relevant parts of your data schema might help.

Comment: do you have any unique id on the rows?

Comment: Sorry, the table has the following columns: device_serial, datetime, triggerID, latitude, longitude, speed, address. The PK consists of the device_serial, datetime, triggerID, latitude, longitude columns.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM
GPSReport AS G1
JOIN (SELECT device_serial, max(datetime) as mostrecent 
      FROM GPSReport group by device_serial) AS G2
ON G2.device_serial = G1.device_serial and g2.mostrecent = g1.datetime
ORDER BY G1.device_serial
```

Comment: If you just need the device and the time code you can use just the sub-query.
SELECT device_serial, max(datetime) as mostrecent 
FROM GPSReport group by device_serial

Comment: It's unlikely, but This might still return duplicates if there are multiple records with same datetime and service_serial. Using the group-by and aggregate functions is definitely the solution though.

Comment: hmmm I don't think so, not on sql-server 2005.  max will only return one value even when the values are the same.  (This is the reason the max() trick works to add in columns of other constant fields to an aggregate query

Comment: This is close, but MandoMando is correct, there are duplicate positions for the same device serial and datetime. The PK for the table consists of the device_serial, datetime, triggerID, latitude, and longitude columns.

Comment: sorry, I see what you mean.
Yes just add the unique list to the inner select with a max() around it and include it in the join
should solve your problem

Answer (score 37):

```
WITH DEDUPE AS (
    SELECT  *
          , ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY what_you_want_for_distinct ORDER BY what_you_want_for_distinct) AS OCCURENCE
    FROM tablename
    )
SELECT  * FROM DEDUPE
WHERE
OCCURENCE = 1
```

Comment: Outstanding, I love it when answers abstract away the details and show the concept. +1

Comment: Your answer is absolutely brilliant.  Thanks so much for posting this.  Huge help.

Comment: Very descriptive. I do, however, think the ORDER BY should be what_you_want_to_select [DESC] instead of what_you_want_for_distinct.

Answer (score 2):

You are having a right join, so if you have more than 1 record for device serial number in table `GPSReport`, it will get all those record and joint then to the unique list received from `SELECT DISTINCT device_serial FROM GPSReport`.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
   Select r.*   
   From GPSReport r
   Where datetime =
        (Select Max(DateTime)
         From GPSReport 
         Where device_serial = r.device_serial)
```

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this - since I couldn't run it, I expect my synatx is not perfect

```
select *
  from (
    select device_serial, [datetime], triggerID, latitude, longitude, speed, [address],
        ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by device_serial order by device_serial asc, [datetime] desc) as row
      from gpsreport
  ) as data
  where row = 1
```

You may need to modify the order by clause to select the preferred record if there are multiples with the same device_serial and datetime

Answer (score 1):

I would do it with a Common Table Expression (CTE), like so:

```
With ResultTable (RowNumber
                 ,device_serial
                 ,datetime
                 ,triggerID
                 ,latitude
                 ,longitude
                 ,speed
                 ,address)
AS
(
    SELECT Row_Number() OVER (PARTITION BY device_serial
                                  ORDER BY datetime DESC)
          ,device_serial
          ,datetime
          ,triggerID
          ,latitude
          ,longitude
          ,speed
          ,address
      FROM GPSReport
)
    SELECT device_serial
          ,datetime
          ,triggerID
          ,latitude
          ,longitude
          ,speed
          ,address
      FROM ResultTable
     WHERE RowNumber = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

I found this amazing result after trying every possible answer on StackOverFlow

```
WITH cte AS /* Declaring a new table named 'cte' to be a clone of your table */
(SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY val1 DESC) AS rn
    FROM MyTable /* Selecting only unique values based on the "id" field */
)
SELECT * /* Here you can specify several columns to retrieve */
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed for MSSQL!

Answer (score 0):

This is the final result do not use distinct , for this is the new query, its helpfull for all  "**select * FROM tbl GROUP BY bandsupported**"  . its work same as distinct one filed and get all rows

Answer (score 0):

The following is for Postgresql 9+.

None of these answers worked for me (yet this was the first link returned by Google for my search). I needed to get only the first row of each set of rows where the given expressions evaluate to equal while dropping the other rows without using any aggregation.

[This answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/159899/137608) showed me how to do it with `DISTINCT ON` (which is different than just `DISTINCT`):

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON(x,y) z, k, r, t, v
FROM foo;
```

In that case, only the first `z` is taken. The rest of the `z`s are discarded from the set.

You can select just one column (which is what I did), instead of two like in the example.

Bear in mind that since there is no `GROUP BY`, you cannot use real aggregation in that query.

Check out the answer from the link for more options. It is very thorough.