# SELECT defined value based on GROUPBY of DISTINCT columns SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table called `darts` that looks as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE "darts" (
    "player"    TEXT,
    "opponent"  TEXT,
    "date"  TEXT,
    "competition"   TEXT,
    "round" TEXT,
    "sets"  REAL,
    "sets won"  REAL,
    "sets lost" REAL,
    "legs"  INTEGER,
    "legs won"  INTEGER,
    "legs lost" INTEGER,
    "opponent score"    INTEGER,
    "score_begin_of_turn"   INTEGER,
    "score_after_first_dart"    INTEGER,
    "score_after_second_dart"   TEXT,
    "score_after_third_dart"    TEXT
);
```

Each row of the db represents a turn of player and the corresponding scores in the turn. Both player start with 0 "sets" and 0 "legs" won and a score of 501. Whereas the data represents the time-series of the matches, I would like to retrieve the "summary" of each match.
With the help of the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1785634/select-distinct-on-one-column-return-multiple-other-columns-sql-server) of howie I wrote the following query

```
player = 'michael van gerwen' 
opponent = 'gerwyn price'

query = f""" WITH DEDUPE AS (
             SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY player, opponent, date, competition, round   
             ORDER BY player, opponent, date, competition, round) AS OCCURENCE
             FROM darts)

             SELECT *
             WHERE OCCURENCE = 1 
             AND player LIKE '{player}' 
             AND opponent LIKE '{opponent}' """
```

This query yields all the unique matches between the two players for each date, tournament and round. The output looks as follows:

```
                player      opponent  ... OCCURENCE
0   Michael van Gerwen  Gerwyn Price  ...  1
1   Michael van Gerwen  Gerwyn Price  ...  1
2   Michael van Gerwen  Gerwyn Price  ...  1
3   Michael van Gerwen  Gerwyn Price  ...  1
4   Michael van Gerwen  Gerwyn Price  ...  1
5   Michael van Gerwen  Gerwyn Price  ...  1
etc
```

However, I would also like to determine the final score. This can be found by using the values in the columns `legs won` and `legs lost`.
I know that the final score is equal to

```
MAX(legs won) and MAX(legs lost)
```

However, the above needs to be grouped again by `player`, `opponent`, `date`, `competition` and `round`. How can I include this into my query? Please advice! Thanks

Desired output:

```
                player      opponent  ...  legs_player legs_opponent
0   Michael van Gerwen  Gerwyn Price  ...   7  5
1   Michael van Gerwen  Gerwyn Price  ...   4  3
2   Michael van Gerwen  Gerwyn Price  ...   2  7
3   Michael van Gerwen  Gerwyn Price  ...   5  6
4   Michael van Gerwen  Gerwyn Price  ...   4  0
5   Michael van Gerwen  Gerwyn Price  ...   0  4
etc
```

Comment: A question should be self-contained, ie, not require reference to other questions to understand. Sample data and desired results will help, please see how to provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). `SELECT * WHERE` is not valid SQL.

Comment: Why do you use ROW_NUMBER() to get the unique matches? A simple query with SELECT DISTINCT ... would be enough. Also, do you mean MAX(legs_won) - MAX(legs_lost) for the final score? Post sample data and expected results to clarify.

Comment: I edited the question in the hope that my problem is better described now. I should have specified the data better.

Comment: Ideally you would provide the sample data that corresponds to your desired results, otherwise there is nothing for anyone to actually use to test a working solution.

Answer (score 0):

Can't be sure without sample data, but it seems you want to aggregate.

```
SELECT player, opponent, date, competition, round
, MAX(`legs won`) AS max_legs_won
, MAX(`legs lost`) AS max_legs_lost
FROM darts
WHERE player LIKE '{player}' 
  AND opponent LIKE '{opponent}'
GROUP BY player, opponent, date, competition, round 
ORDER BY player, opponent, date, competition, round
```